# Jupyter Notebook - number seperator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I try to display large numbers with seperators in jupyter notebooks. I know how i can set this in pandas, but how can I set it for normal variables like

```
In[0] : 1234567
out[1]: 1234567 # would like 1.234.567
```

Is that possible with a global setting, maybe in python itself, without formating it explicitly on every line?

Comment: You mean comma or dot?

Comment: Yes, like the the example